# How to allow app run longer while it is in background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a Swift program that gets the user location based on certain conditions and save the location to a local database.

The application can also run on the background state. Since I need to get a very accurate location, it can take up to 60 seconds to get the location. If location is determine in less than 5 sec, everything works fine while app is running on the background. If it takes more than 5 secs to get the location, then nothing will happen. I think the reason is because you have only a few seconds to complete the background task.

So is it possible to request up to 60 secs for the background task to run? Do I need to add any special code to tell the OS please allow more time (up to 60 secs) for the background task to complete?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Use the `UIApplication` function `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`. In recent versions of iOS That gives you 3 minutes to finish whatever it is you're doing. See the Xcode docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler'

Sample code can be like this:

```
var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

    func registerBackgroundTask() {
  backgroundTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler {
    [unowned self] in
    self.endBackgroundTask()
  }
  assert(backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
}

func endBackgroundTask() {
  NSLog("Background task ended.")
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
  backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}
```

More information regarding this can be found in this tutorial about background modes: [Raywenderlich:Background modes - Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial)
[Apple Doc: Background Modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to run your app in background and always on is to keep enable the background mode provided by xcode it self

please refer : https://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial

Also set Bool "Application does not run in the background" in info.plist in your application

Hope this will help

Thank you